# What is Prahlad Chanting

Tags: vishnu, mantras

I am watching [video on Shri Krishna](https://youtu.be/srXGB1kHj9U?t=9m4s). Please tell me what [Prahlad is chanting](https://youtu.be/srXGB1kHj9U?t=9m4s).

They don't mention in subtitles, and it's hard for me to understand. (I speak English only.)

Thank You.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The mantra being chanted is "oṁ namo bhagavate vāsudevāya", which means "Om! Salutations to Bhagavan Vāsudeva."  Bhagavan literally means the one who has wealth, but in this context it means "supreme being".  And Vāsudeva is a name of Vishnu.  In any case, this mantra occurs in the very first verse of the Srimad Bhagavatam, which says [this](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/1/1/1):

> **oṁ namo bhagavate vāsudevāya** 
>  
>   janmādy asya yato ’nvayād itarataś cārtheṣv abhijñaḥ svarāṭ 
>  
>   tene brahma hṛdā ya ādi-kavaye muhyanti yat sūrayaḥ 
>  
>   tejo-vāri-mṛdāṁ yathā vinimayo yatra tri-sargo ’mṛṣā 
>  
>   dhāmnā svena sadā nirasta-kuhakaṁ satyaṁ paraṁ dhīmahi
>
> O my Lord, Śrī Kṛṣṇa, son of Vasudeva, O all-pervading Personality of Godhead, I offer my respectful obeisances unto You. I meditate upon Lord Śrī Kṛṣṇa because He is the Absolute Truth and the primeval cause of all causes of the creation, sustenance and destruction of the manifested universes. He is directly and indirectly conscious of all manifestations, and He is independent because there is no other cause beyond Him. It is He only who first imparted the Vedic knowledge unto the heart of Brahmājī, the original living being. By Him even the great sages and demigods are placed into illusion, as one is bewildered by the illusory representations of water seen in fire, or land seen on water. Only because of Him do the material universes, temporarily manifested by the reactions of the three modes of nature, appear factual, although they are unreal. I therefore meditate upon Him, Lord Śrī Kṛṣṇa, who is eternally existent in the transcendental abode, which is forever free from the illusory representations of the material world. I meditate upon Him, for He is the Absolute Truth.

I discuss this verse in my question [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/12393/36), by the way.

On a side note, it's great that you're watching Shri Krishna.  I watched that show when I was in Kindergarten, and it was one of the main shows that got me interested in learning more about Hinduism. It led me to read Amar Chitra Katha comic books, which greatly increased my knowledge of Hindu stories and ultimately led me to start reading Hindu scripture.

Comment: In Kindergarten? I'll certainly have my future children watch this. And those Amar Chitra Comics are wonderful. Wish they still sell them, or are available in USA.

Comment: @Rhonda Yeah, in Kindergarten and earlier I watched many TV serials including Ramayan, Sri Krishna, and Vishwamitra.  My parents and other family members used to read the subtitles out loud to me, since at that age I couldn't read the subtitles quickly enough.  The animated Ramayana movie is another thing I loved.  In any case, Amar Chitra Kathas are available in many temple bookstores in the U.S., but if you want I can email some of them to you in PDF format.  My email address is in my profile page.

Comment: I just sent you email. Thank you so much.

Comment: Do you have any source or reference in the scripture for this that prahlad Maharaj I chanting on namo bhagavate vasudevaya